# auto-py-to-exe converted python file, fails to execute

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, exe, file-conversion

I have a simple scipt that gives me the time to a specific date and i'm using pyinstaller with this command to convert it to a .exe file to give to my friend:

`pyinstaller --onefile --windowed  "D:/Documents/code/own/python/sages_birthday/time_till_meetup.py"`

When i then try to execute the created file i get this window as an error:
[image: error_message]

I have made a file with `--console` instead of `--windowed` to try and get more information, but i didn't even get the error to pop up or any other information.

Comment: It can't seem to find the module and gives me this error:
```Error: The 'win'10toast' distribution was not found and is required by the application```

followed by a Traceback error message.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add Python to Windows Path
Step 2: Open the Windows Command Prompt
Step 3: Install the Pyinstaller Package
                             `pip install pyinstaller`

Step 4: Save your Python Script
Step 5: Create the Executable using Pyinstaller
            `cd followed by the location where your Python script is stored`
Step 6: pyinstaller --onefile pythonScriptName.py
Step 7: Run the Executable
Few additional files got created at that location. To find the executable
file, open the dist folder:

Comment: i did that and it didn't work, but it might be one of the modules that i was using. I'm replacing it now and hopefully it works.

Comment: it did not help for a fact.